# Replicating behavior of AllowCredentials() extension method of CORS middleware in .net core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

I am trying to replicate behavior of `AllowCredentials()` method in a Middleware, Due to some business requirement I need to allow the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header based on some condition. So instead of using some `AllowCredentials()` of CORS middleware I have added
this line of code in my middleware

```
if (foo)
{
   context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
}
```

it works on GET APIs but for POST APIs it is not working. below is my startup code

```
services
                .AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(
                        allowSpecificOrigins,
                        builder =>
                        {
                            builder
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                                .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
                                .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition", "X-Suggested-Filename", "Request-Id")
                                .WithMethods(HttpMethod.Get.ToString(), HttpMethod.Post.ToString(), HttpMethod.Options.ToString());
                        });
                });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Note : I have also set withCredentials = true on the Front end side (vue.js)

EDIT: My Configure method

```
public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            FileLogger.LogInformation("Start Configure");

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(allowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders();

            FileLogger.LogInformation("Register Routing");
            app.UseRouting();

            FileLogger.LogInformation("Register Foo Middleware");
            app.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware1>();
            app.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware2>();
            app.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware3>();

            FileLogger.LogInformation("Register Endpoints");
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: You need to share your **entire** `Configure()` method - and not your `ConfigureServices` method either.

Comment: @Dai Added configure method as asked

Comment: What is `FooMiddleware` and why is it added 3 times?

Comment: @Dai those are three middleware I require. I can't give you my whole code as it is

Comment: `AddCors` *is* middleware. Why are you trying to reimplement it? What does your middleware do? How did you determine it doesn't work? Some kinds of requests [don't trigger CORS checks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests), including FORM POSTs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not trying to reimplement CORS If you read the question carefully, I have a requirement where I need this header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials in a select few APIs, not all. When I don't use the AllowCredentials method provided by CORS middleware my GET requests work fine but POST gives me a CORS error.

Comment: You can do that by adding more policies with different origins. `SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)` is essentially the same as `AllowAllOrigings()`,  a bad idea as it effectively calling allows all URLs. It makes using different policies per URL harder as you have to ensure other policies are added before it, otherwise they'll be overriden. It *can* be used to select specific URLs though.

Comment: In any case, you haven't posted the code of *your* middleware. Whatever calculates `foo` produces the wrong value. We can't guess what's going on without the code. The headers are returned in the `OPTIONS` request sent by the server. Perhaps the code forgot to add `POST` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header? Perhaps it's missing other headers correctly set up by the CORS middleware?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand. But, try to change the order of line `app.UseCors(allowSpecificOrigins);`

Put it after the correct `app.UseMiddleware<FooMiddlewareX>();`

The middleware are chained and their order is important